# cannot load such file -- mygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have created a gem called "mygem"(dummy name).

I have built the gem using cmd

```
gem build mygem
```

and I have installed the gem as well.

I checked the installation by running

```
gem list
```

My gem is listed correctly

But in the irb I am not able to load the gem. Running

```
require "mygem"
```

is thorughing the following error

```
cannot load such file -- myGem
```

Below is my gemspec

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "mygem"
  spec.version       = Mygem::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["ABC"]
  spec.email         = ["ABC@example.com"]
  spec.summary       = %q{TODO:}
  spec.description   = %q{TODO:}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
  spec.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split("\n")
  spec.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.6"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec"
end
```

It will be great if you can help me out in this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have created `myGem.rb` (or like) file, containing `myGem` class and forget to add it to `git`.

Why git? Because you use git to build the list of files for your gem:

```
spec.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
```

To solve the issue you should either specify files to include explicitly, or add all the necessary files to git (so that `git ls-files` command returns everything needed for gem to be run properly.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my working dir, if I run git ls-files. Its listing "mygem.rb" file as well. This file is inside lib folder

Comment: Would you mind to grep your working directory for (case sensitive) `myGem` and update the question with results?

Comment: You can looking into the gem source code here https://github.com/Karthikds/randomiser

Comment: I have cloned the source, built gem, installed it with `gem install --local randomiser-0.0.1.gem` and require in irb works perfectly for me. The problem should be with your environment.

Comment: If so, As I have ruby -1.9.3 and ruby 2.0 installed using rvm, may be this is causing the issue.

Comment: Definitely. It seems that you install gem in one ruby’s gemset, while irb uses another one. Try to remove `1.9.3` and use the `rvm` version only. This should resolve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

May be some file or class name is wrong?

The fact that the error says "myGem" instead of "mygem" makes me think that you have something like my_gem.rb or class MyGem somewhere